# Escape the quotes in a C# string

Tags: c#, string, replace, escaping

I wrote a method in C# that takes a string and escapes all of its quotes. It escapes them so that `"` turns into `\"`, which turns into `\\\"`, which turns into `\\\\\\\"`, and so on.

The two arguments are `input` and `depth`. Depth determines simply how many times to escape it. With a depth of 1, the string `He says "hello"` becomes `He says \"hello\"`, whereas with a depth of 2 it becomes `He says \\\"hello\\\"`.

```
private string escapestring(string input, int depth)
    {
        string result = input;
        for (int i = 20; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int nsearch = ((int)Math.Pow(2, i)) - 1;
            int nplus = ((int)Math.Pow(2, i + depth) - 1);
            string search = new string('\\', nsearch);
            search += "\"";
            result = result.Replace(search, "ESCAPE_REPLACE:" + (nplus).ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 20; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int nsearch = ((int)Math.Pow(2, i)) - 1;
            string replace = new string('\\', nsearch);
            replace += "\"";
            result = result.Replace("ESCAPE_REPLACE:" + nsearch.ToString(), replace);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is what I created to solve this task. It's really horrible, simply replacing every set of backslashes followed by a quote that fit the `2^X-1` pattern with some arbitrary blob, then replacing the arbitrary blob with an escaped version. It only works up to 20 and is basically terrible.

By itself, I suppose it would work fine, but I'm calling this repeatedly in a loop later on, and the 40 loops every time it's called is hitting performance hard.

Any thoughts for how to clean this thing up? I still consider myself quite an amateur, so I might be missing something incredibly easy, but my searches haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what all the maths is for, but this will do it:

```
private string escapestring(string input, int depth)
{
    var numSlashes = (int)(Math.Pow(2, depth)-1);
    return input.Replace("\"", new string('\\', numSlashes)+"\"");
}
```

Comment: That just sticks a number of backslashes equal to depth behind each quote. It needs to escape in a pattern of 0, 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, etc.

Comment: OK, so you are using a Mersenne number sequence. Try it now.

Comment: That's so simple I feel like an idiot. Thanks for your help!